# How to display only logged in user's post comments in comments area

Tags: admin, comments, wp-admin, users, user-access

I am making a custom Wordpress site where School students logged in and add their posts. 
I am giving them rights to use wp-admin panel with little customization and modification.

***QUESTION:*** "How can logged in user be able to see comments of his own post only in edit comment admin panel"

please suggest me some solution i am in need for the same

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i had been looking for the code where logged in users will be able to see post of his own only i have managed to make simple function that we can use for the same the function snippet has to be included in functions .php file in the theme folder which you are using

```
function my_plugin_get_comment_list_by_user($clauses) 

{

if (is_admin()) 

{

  global $user_ID, $wpdb;

  $clauses['join'] = ", wp_posts";

  $clauses['where'] .= " AND wp_posts.post_author = ".$user_ID." AND wp_comments.comment_post_ID = wp_posts.ID";

 };

 return $clauses;

}
```

// Ensure that editors and admins can moderate all comments

```
if(!current_user_can('edit_others_posts')) 

{

 add_filter('comments_clauses', 'my_plugin_get_comment_list_by_user');

}
```

Thanks 
NIkhil Joshi

Comment: Well done, if only you would have included a way to fix the comment count