# How to get comments with mixed status using get_comments?

Tags: functions, comments

Is there a way to get comments with more than one `status` using [`get_comments`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_comments) function?

Let's say I would like to get both `trash` and `hold` comments.

It is possible to do the same with posts:

```
get_posts(array('post_status' => 'draft,private,trash'));
get_posts(array('post_status' => array('draft', 'private', 'trash')));
```

What I want to do is:

```
get_comments(array('status' => 'hold,trash'));
get_comments(array('status' => array('hold', 'trash')));
```

Comment: Update, in case anyone's finding this: `status` now accepts an array or a comma-separated list of statuses (stati?): https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_comment_query/__construct/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of the Wordpress codex there is no such option. But you could just combine two or more comment arrays using plain PHP:

```
array_merge(
    get_comments( array( 'status' => 'hold' ) ),
    get_comments( array( 'status' => 'trash' ) )
);
```

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_comments

http://php.net/array_merge

Comment: Make sure both parts are actually arrays. The function can return `NULL` in some cases, `array_merge()` will trigger an error then.

Comment: Yeah, I know PHP quite well :)

Comment: Works nicely for approved and unapproved comments. The merge even supports correct threading for unapproved comments.

Answer (score 2):

Not possible. You have to filter `comments_clauses`:

```
add_filter( 'comments_clauses', 'wpse_77415_comment_clauses_filter' );

function wpse_77415_comment_clauses_filter( $clauses )
{
    $clauses['where'] .= " ( comment_approved = 'hold' OR comment_approved = 'trash' )";
    // maybe remove the original 'comment_approved' statement …

    return $clauses;
}
```

More examples:

- [Get comments for more than one post](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/55164/get-comments-for-more-than-one-post/55210#55210)
- [Get a variable field of all comments of current post](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/76150/73)
- [How to display only logged in user's post comments in comments area](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/50390/73)

Comment: Seems you know WordPress better than @feeela, but his method is more simple and more convenient. Thanks, for the code, anyway, maybe I will use it in the future. +1

Comment: "Not possible." Well, you provided a solution that made it possible…

Comment: It's not possible do do it just like that, you need to filter the sql clause.